# nested FOREACH statements

Tags: apache-pig

It seems that group is not supported in nested FOREACH statements. I have the following schema:

```
data2: {group: chararray,data1: {(lt: chararray,ln: chararray)}}
```

on which I want to flatten data1, group all pairs of (lt, ln), count, order DESC, and finally limit 1.

The idea is to extract the most probable pair of (lt, ln) for each group. How would you recommend me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fastest execution a UDF would be best. 
In pure Apache Pig it would be nice if you could do count on (group, lt, ln) before creating a relation with your schema. It woul be something like this (it is just a pseudo script, might need some debugging)

```
Assuming load schema is (id, lt, ln)

inpt = LOAD ....... as (id, lt : chararray, ln : chararray);
grp1 = GROUP inpt BY (id, lt, ln);
data1 = FOREACH grp FLATTEN(inpt), COUNT(data1) as cnt;
data2 = GROUP data_wtih_count BY id;
--data2: {group: chararray,data1: {(id, lt: chararray,ln: chararray, cnt : int)}}
most_probable_pair = FOREACH data2 {
  ord = ORDER data1 BY cnt ASC;
  top = LIMIT ord 1;
  GENERATE group, top.(ln, lt);
}
```

Or you could flatten data2 and data1 and start with grp1.

Comment: great. it worked. quick question: what makes you believe that a UDF would be less computational expensive? your judgement is based on what?

Comment: If the bags are not too large, I think less than 90MB each, than with UDF you might get away with a single "GROUP BY" and not 2. Each "GROUP BY" causes one map reduce job. As there is no filtering and all data is carried through both group by operations it will take twice the time compared to UDF implementation with a single group by (single map reduce job).